# setting comment face in major mode on multi-line word-delimited comments

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, comment

I am working on a major mode for an input file format I am interested in and want to set multi-line comments with the delimiters skip and noskip like

```
skip larb noskip
```

or

```
skip 
GRID
  TYPE structured
  NXYZ 284 307 1
END
noskip
```

Using the re-builder, I came upon the following regex that highlights both single and multi-line comments

```
"skip\\(.\\|\n\\)*?noskip"
```

But this doesn't work to pass to the font-lock-comment-face. Only the single-line version gets its font-locked.

Is there a mode with word-delimited multi-line comments like I  want, that I can borrow the right syntax from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than handle it in font-lock highlighing rules, you want to handle it at the level of syntax tables.  Now syntax-tables can't directly handle such start/end markers, so you'll have to use the *syntax-propertize* system.  E.g.

```
(setq-local syntax-propertize-function
  (syntax-propertize-rules
    ("\\_<\\(s\\)kip\\_>" (1 "<"))
    ("\\_<noski\\(p\\)\\_>" (1 ">"))))
```

An important difference between font-lock rules and syntax-propertize rules is that font-lock rules can be applied "out of order" or piecemeal.  More specifically, by default Emacs only applies font-lock rules to the parts of the buffer that are displayed, so if the `skip` in your code happens to be in a part of the buffer which was never displayed, the font-lock rules will simply miss it.

Another important difference is that font-lock rules don't naturally have state, so you either need to use one regexp which matches the multi-line element (and then try and force font-lock to always consider a large enough chunk of the buffer to see both `skip` and `noskip` at the same time) or to separately match `skip`, `noskip`, and every line between them, and to each time check whether we're still within a skip..noskip thingy.

Comment: Maybe say *why* Kris wants to handle it this way rather than that way.