# font-lock keywords and syntax-table mutually interfering

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, syntax-table

I would like to define something that font-locks a bit like a new sort of string-literal/comment.  I might write:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp-mode
   (list '("<<.*>>" 0 'my-custom-face prepend)))
```

I'm using `'emacs-lisp-mode` as my example just because it's an existing mode with syntax-table driven string literal and comment highlighting.
As per [How to highlight specific keywords inside strings/quotes?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-highlight-specific-keywords-inside-strings-quotes?rq=1) the `prepend` above ensures that my new delimiters take precedence, so that

```
<<"foo" bar>>
```

font locks entirely with the new face.  I'm happy enough with that.  But I would like

```
; some comment text <<foo>>
```

to highlight with the comment colors, and for

```
"some string stuff <<foo>>"
```

to highlight entirely with string-literal colors.  Unfortunately, I get the custom face appearing within the literals and comments, which is distracting and arguably wrong (certainly, string literals and comments are mutually compatible).  How do I get the outermost delimiters to take precedence?

(Annoyingly, if I don't have the `prepend`, the syntax-table stuff takes precedence particularly dramatically: something like `<<foo bar>>` is fine, but `<<"foo" bar>>` has the `"foo"` in string literal colors, and doesn't color the delimiters or the `bar` at all.)

Comment: It looks like the approach of making everything syntax-table driven (as per https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20434/setting-comment-face-in-major-mode-on-multi-line-word-delimited-comments?rq=1) might work, but then I wouldn't get to use my own custom face...

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly like the solution, but I used a function matcher that called `re-search-forward` to find the start delimiter, and then checked the return code of `syntax-ppss` to see if the position was in a comment or string literal.

This looped forward until it ran out of room (*i.e.,* respecting the provided `limit` parameter), or found a left-delimiter not inside comment or string syntax.  Having done that, it could then search forward for the right delimiter and then return the appropriate match-data if it found one.

Comment: I've this approach a lot in the past. It typically work well and you don't have to fiddle with the syntax table.